# outputting a character on the console from within hlasm (370)

Tags: mainframe

For fun I'm implementing brainfuck compilers translating bf to e.g. x86 assembly. Currently I'm working on bf to mainframe assembly. Dialect is "HLASM" and mainframe is one of IBM with a 370.

Sofar most of it works only emitting a character to the console of the operator fails: I only get spaces and it looks like an implicit linefeed is added (which I don't want).

Can anyone find my mistake?

```
* get a character to display
         LLGC  R6,0(R7)
* get a pointer to the buffer which will contain the char to displa
         LA    R5,BUFFER
* store character in buffer
         STC   R6,0(R5)
* get a pointer to the memory area describing the data to display
         LA    R1,MSGAREA
* invoke display char
         SVC   35

MSGAREA  EQU   *
         DC    AL2(5)
         DC    XL2'00'
BUFFER   DC    C'!'
```

Comment: Are you certain you want output to go to the console?  Normally output is written to either the `SYSOUT` or `SYSPRINT` `DD`.  Your mention of the addition of a LF leads me to believe you are confusing "console" for "terminal."

Comment: @cschneid yes you're right, I mean the terminal the user is connected to

Comment: I would suggest writing to the `SYSOUT` `DD`.  You'll need to code a `DCB` macro for `SYSOUT` and then use the `OPEN` and `PUT` macros.  Be advised the I/O is record oriented and not stream oriented so I think you'll have to buffer your output.

Comment: @cschneid do you happen to have example code? If so, please put it in an answer, not a comment, so that I can tick it as *the* answer. That gives you reputationpoints. regards

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest writing to the `SYSOUT` `DD` to give you the flexibility to run either in batch (allocating `SYSOUT` in your `JCL`) or interactively (allocating `SYSOUT` to the terminal session which I believe is the default in `TSO`).

```
[entry logic, initialization and so forth]
         OPEN  (SYSOUT,OUTPUT)
         
         PUT   SYSOUT,RECORD
         
         CLOSE SYSOUT
[exit logic]         
         
RECORD   DC    CL80' '   
SYSOUT   DCB   DDNAME=SYSOUT,                                          X
               DSORG=PS,                                               X
               MACRF=PM,                                               X
               RECFM=FB,                                               X
               LRECL=80
```

You might want to also look at the [TPUT, TGET, and TPG macros](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=io-overview-tget-tput-tpg-macro-instructions) for terminal I/O if you're okay with tying your program to running in TSO exclusively.  Terminal I/O is kind of odd in a 3270 environment if you're used to streaming I/O as in Unix.

`DCB` is documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=descriptions-dcbconstruct-data-control-block-qsam). `OPEN` is documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=nvmd-openconnect-program-data-bdam-bisam-interface-vsam-bpam-bsam-qisam-interface-vsam-qsam). `PUT` is documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=descriptions-putwrite-next-record-qsam).  `CLOSE` is documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=nvmd-closedisconnect-program-data-bdam-bisam-bpam-bsam-qisam-qsam).

Comment: To add to the answer above, a few lines of code can tell you whether you're in a TSO session or not...just check the ASCB field ASCBTSB - nonzero means you're in a TSO session and can use TPUT/TGET.

Comment: One other thing is that you can also opt to run under the UNIX Service shell and in assembler, you'd call BPX1WRT to write bytes to the STDOUT file handle. This would work pretty much like any other *NIX flavor.

Comment: @cschnid: since you don't know where this code will run, it would be a great idea to update your sample to be reentrant. Also, as for "allocating SYSOUT to the terminal session which I believe is the default in TSO", there's no actual default here - many sites put //SYSOUT DD TERM=TS in the TSO session JCL, but you can't rely on this.

Comment: @ValerieR I attempted to use BPX1WRT as you suggested but hit a snag on the link. Would love some help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77632641/link-error-trying-to-call-bpx1wrt-in-assembler-on-z-os

Answer (score 0):

@mike - the documentation is here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/3.1.0?topic=descriptions-write-bpx1wrt-bpx4wrt-write-file-socket. In the appendix are some code examples - it's not really any different than the "write()" C runtime function.