# I am writing my hello-world HL/ASM program using BPX1WRT and it fails because it is not re-entrant

Tags: assembly, zos

I am (re) learning HL/ASM on z/OS and wanted to start with the basics - hello world.
All the examples I could find either:

- wrote to the operator console (WTO), which I can't do in my shop, because it is too noisy
- were not re-entrant (in non-z/OS terms, the code wasn't read-only)

Does someone have an example?

I am (re) learning HL/ASM on z/OS and wanted to start with the basics - hello world.
All the examples I could find either:

- wrote to the operator console (WTO), which I can't do in my shop, because it is too noisy
- were not re-entrant (in non-z/OS terms, the code wasn't read-only)

Does someone have an example?

Answer (score 3):

Unlike other languages, there is not a lot of information on HL/ASM, re-entrancy, UNIX System Services that I could find via Stack Overflow (or google).

Here is a working example:

```
* BPX1WRT: https://tech.mikefulton.ca/bpx1wrt
* BPX1RED: https://tech.mikefulton.ca/bpx1red
* HL/ASM 'RENT' https://tech.mikefulton.ca/asmrentvideo
* BPX Service call: https://tech.mikefulton.ca/callbpxsvc
*
        PRINT ON,GEN,DATA
HELLO   CSECT
HELLO   RMODE ANY
HELLO   AMODE 31
*
* Prolog
*
        SAVE (14,12)
        BASR R12,0
        USING *,R12
        STORAGE OBTAIN,LENGTH=DYNL,ADDR=(R11)
        USING DYNAREA,R11

        LA R2,DSA
        ST R2,8(,R13)
        ST R13,DSA+4
        LR R13,R2
*
* Body
* Write Hello World to STDOUT
*

*
* Store values into parameter list
*
        MVC REC(HWL),HW
        LA  R1,REC
        ST  R1,RECA
        LA  R1,HWL
        ST  R1,RECL
        L   R1,STDOUT
        ST  R1,FD
        L   R1,BPXALET
        ST  R1,ALET

        CALL  BPX1WRT,(FD,                                             x
               RECA,                                                   x
               ALET,                                                   x
               RECL,                                                   x
               RV,                                                     x
               RC,                                                     x
               RN),MF=(E,BPXWRTD)

        L   R8,RV
        L   R9,RC
        L   R10,RN
*
* Epilog
*
        L   R13,DSA+4
        STORAGE RELEASE,LENGTH=DYNL,ADDR=(R11)
        RETURN (14,12),RC=0

*
* Statics, Dynamic Storage, Equates follows
*
* Naming convention:
* Suffixes:
*  L : length
*  S : static
*  D : dynamic
*  A : address

        LTORG
*
* Statics (constants)
*
STDIN   DC F'0'
STDOUT  DC F'1'
STDERR  DC F'2'
BPXALET DC F'0'
BPX1WRT DC V(BPX1WRT)

BPXWRTS CALL  ,(0,0,0,0,0,0,0),MF=L
BPXWRTL EQU *-BPXWRTS

HW      DC C'Hello World'
NEWLINE DC X'15'
HWL     EQU *-HW

*
* Dynamic (storage obtain'ed) area
*
DYNAREA DSECT
*
* Dynamic Save Area regs always first
*
DSA   DS 18F

*
* Working storage
*
FD      DS  F

RECSIZE EQU RECEND-*
REC     DS CL80
RECEND  EQU *
RECA    DS  A
BPXWRTD DS  CL(BPXWRTL)
ALET    DS  F
RECL    DS  F
RV      DS  F
RC      DS  F
RN      DS  F

DYNL EQU *-DYNAREA
*
*
* End of working storage
*

*
* Equates
*
R0      EQU 0
R1      EQU 1
R2      EQU 2
R3      EQU 3
R4      EQU 4
R5      EQU 5
R6      EQU 6
R7      EQU 7
R8      EQU 8
R9      EQU 9
R10     EQU 10
R11     EQU 11
R12     EQU 12
R13     EQU 13
R14     EQU 14
R15     EQU 15
        END
```

To assemble and link, make sure you pull in the `SYS1.CSSLIB` code for BPX1WRT:

```
as -mlist hw.asm >hw.lst
ld -S "//'SYS1.CSSLIB'" hw.o
```

You can now run `./a.out` to get:

```
Hello World
```

Comment: Glad to see you got this working! BTW, in my opinion, a much better solution than linking in the BPX... routines is to use the offsets IBM documents in the documentation to simply load the address and branch accordingly - no need for the V-con or the CSSLIB in the link this way. Some of us create something like a "BPX" macro that does this for us so we can use the assembler UNIX Services interfaces without needing to link the stubs (or have the overhead of LINX, etc). Another BTW is that you shouldn't need the V(BPX1WRT)...the CALL macro generates an =V(BPX1WRT) - look at the expansion.